# Android - Show/Hide imageView with ToggleButton

Tags: android, imageview, hide, android-relativelayout, show

I am trying to hide/show an imageView by using a toggleButton, but it does not work.
Here is my code of the related parts:
XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Switch
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textOff="auto"
    android:textOn="manuel" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/compass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/compass" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/compass_direction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/compass_direction"
    android:rotation="180" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here the JAVA-part:

```
public class SnowActivity extends MenuActivity implements SensorEventListener,
    OnCheckedChangeListener, OnTouchListener, ScrollViewListener {

    private Switch toggleButton;
    private ImageView compass;
    private ImageView compass_direction;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_snow);

    toggleButton = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    compass = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compass);
    compass_direction = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compass_direction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    sensorEnabled = !isChecked;
    if (sensorEnabled) {
        compass.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        compass_direction.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        compass.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        compass_direction.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
}
```

If I manually add the visible tag on the imageView in xml with

```
android:visibility = "visible"
```

it's working. At least the pics are hidden in the 'Graphical Layout', but programmatically it doesn't. Besides I also have additional methods which are called in the onCheckedChange() method, so the ToggleButton seems to be implemented correctly.

Thanks in advance!
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Set your tools:context attribute in your xml layout to .SnowActivity instead of .MainActivity.

Comment: The `tools` attributes don't affect anything at runtime.

Comment: Ok, my bad.  If I were to debug it, I'd log the value of sensorEnabled inside the onCheckedChanged (Log.i("SnowActivity", "SensorEnabled flag is "+Boolean.toString(sensorEnabled));)